# PDO MYSQL SUM AND GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have this code

```
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT item_id, SUM(item_quantity) FROM delivery_pending_items WHERE dp_id=:dp_id GROUP BY item_id ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':dp_id'=>$dp_id));

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $stmt;
```

Here is the table sample

```
Item_Id Item_quantity 
1        10
1        20
```

What I need to do is to group the item_id and add the quantity and get the result like this

```
item_id=1 item_quantity=30
```

Comment: Your query should already be doing this.  What output are you actually getting?

Comment: item_id is the only parameter that has been returned, item_quantity was missing

Comment: Try using `$stmt->execute()` followed by `$result = $stmt->fetchAll()`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on array

Comment: hi whats the output did you get?

Comment: @NewbeeDev Hi im getting the value of item_id but item_quantity is a undefine variable

Comment: maybe you assign an alias to it `SUM(item_quantity) as sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem why it returns undefined because you haven't assign an alias to it

where you try it

```
$result['Item_quantity']
```

but it dont exist in result

the output of the result is

```
item_id SUM(item_quantity)
    1           30
```

to solve that add an alias to it

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    SUM(item_quantity) AS Item_quantity
FROM
    delivery_pending_items
WHERE
    dp_id =: dp_id
GROUP BY
    item_id
```

> edited: I change alias sum to Item_quantity lately

Comment: Also try `print_r($result)` to see everything that's in the result.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT(f.Item_id), s.TotalQuantity FROM Items AS f JOIN (SELECT Item_Id, SUM(Item_Name) AS TotalQuantity FROM Items GROUP BY Item_Id ) AS s ON f.Item_id = s.Item_id